# How to get User information in strongloop using angular.js

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I've tried many ways to get the users list/functions using strongloop and the generated angular.js services using lb-ng. Every time I try to get any User functionality, I get a message not authorized.

Why would the generated service file contain User functions and not be able to call it from front end. Many articles say it's intentional. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Here's the code I'm using to check duplicate user.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'User',
        function ($scope, User) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.verificationSent = false;
            $scope.duplicateUser = false;

            $scope.create = function () {
                User
                    .create($scope.data)
                    .$promise
                    .then(function () {
                        $scope.verificationSent = true;
                        console.log('User %s created successfully!', $scope.data['username']);
                    })
            }

            $scope.usernameExists = function () {
                User
                    .findOne({
                        where: {
                            username: $scope.data['username']
                        }
                    })
                    .$promise
                    .then(function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    })
            }

        }
    ])
```

Here's how I'm calling from front end.

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && usernameExists()" novalidate>
```

Here's the error that's returned.

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Users/findOne?where=%7B%22username%22:%22test%22%7D 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Attached a screenshot too...
I'm trying this out for many weeks now, kindly help...

[image: getting the existing user with same username]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend service created by strongloop requires the correct authorization  which you are missing in your call. The /Users get call is configured to DENY all requests, if you want to open it up then you have to explicitly state this. But be careful when you are performing this operation, you could expose private user credentials which is usually undesirable. What you want to do is create a server-side call which checks if the username is a duplicate and responds accordingly, and you can have this call be ALLOWED to everyone, and then call this from Angular and do what you need. Hope that explanation was clear.

UPDATE
Here is a guide to modifying ACLs: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access

Comment: Authorized users should be able to view the users list. Also add roles to users or perform any other options. This is only possible if a list of users is available on the application. One cannot expect Admin to go to database for making any modification.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant, you will have to set the access controls on the server side as per your requirement. By default the user list is set to deny.

Comment: Can you point me how to set the ACL for user? As far as I've seen it's in the loopback folder, which may be overwritten each time it's pushed/pulled from/to git. Any I tried setting ACLs from running slc loopback:acl, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This documents everything: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Authentication%2C+authorization%2C+and+permissions, if you still can't figure it out then please post a more specific question

Comment: I would say I was looking for this https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-playground

Comment: You can also look at modifying ACLs here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access

Comment: Thanks, I've already created another model called customers which derives from the in-built user model and changed the default acl to suite my needs.  But, just confused if this was proper way. Because this will lead to making many other models derive from user model and make it difficult to manage. eg, if I've to store employee data then I can't use the customer table/model. employee is also another user. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can use Roles and RoleMappings in this case. Create the roles as Customer, Employee etc. and then at the time of creating the user you can assign the correct role. Then you can grant permissions on resources based on roles. This is also covered in the documentation

Comment: So create a model with name Person which derives from User. Modify Person to suite your needs. Add Roles with Customer and Employee. But then if I've to get a list of Employees then I'll have to join with Roles. However, this seems OK with current scenario. Thanks!